# Calculating player rank based on games played

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to display a chart where can show game, score, all-time rank, weekly rank, rank with friends.

I have two tables:
1) high_scores (playerid, gameid, score, time(timestamp))
2) friends (playerid, friendid)

I was wondering how I can do so using the minimum number of queries.

I'm using PHP & MySQL for my game site.

Comment: Quite a few clarifications required: do you mean, after each game, display the game score as well as where it sits in the all-time ranking and week? Define week, is it the last 7 calendar days, the last 24x7 hours, the current week starting Monday etc? Rank with friends - does this break down by week as well? Does it show unique friends only based on the best high score for each friend?

Answer (score 1):

could manage to make query for it as follow:

```
SELECT
    gamescores.gameid,
    COUNT(*)+1 AS rank,
    playergamescores.total,
    gamename,
    foldername
FROM (
    SELECT gameid, playerid, SUM( score ) AS total, time
    FROM high_scores
    GROUP BY gameid, playerid
    ORDER BY gameid, total DESC
) AS gamescores
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT gameid, SUM(score) AS total
    FROM high_scores
    WHERE playerid = 361822
    GROUP BY gameid
    ORDER BY total DESC
) AS playergamescores
ON playergamescores.gameid = gamescores.gameid
INNER JOIN gamemaster
ON gamescores.gameid = gamemaster.gameid
WHERE gamescores.total > (
    SELECT SUM( score ) AS total
    FROM high_scores
    WHERE gamescores.gameid = gameid
    AND playerid = 361822                       
)
GROUP BY gamescores.gameid
ORDER BY gamescores.time DESC
```

Thanks for answering anyway...
-Navi

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your data once, not at every requests.

You have 2 solutions:

- a cron/async job
- triggers recomputing stats after each insert/update/delete/truncate